# passing variables through url in DRUPAL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Whenever I try to pass a variable through url with the `l()` function like:

```
l(t($row['salon_name']),'admin/content/edit-salons-products-services?sid='.$row[salon_id] );
```

? is replaced by "%3F"

= is replaced by "%3D"

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: That is by design and necessary, it's called URL encoding. Why is it a problem?

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278135/i-want-to-use-the-question-mark-in-the-auto-generated-path-aliases, just for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to: `'admin/content/edit-salons-products-services/.$row[salon_id]'`.

You can access the salon id with `arg(3)`.

You may also need to change your module's menu declaration to allow this URL.

Comment: thank u finbarr, so I ask u a 2nd question : How to check by default deme checboxes in drupal fapi checkboxes

Comment: @Mamadou If you have a separate question, you should create a new question instead of asking in this one

Answer (score 1):

As Finbarr said, it's often better to pass variables as path components, rather than query parameters, but query parameters are still possible with l().

Query parameters are passed into l() outside the base $path, in the $options parameter. This makes it easier to programmatically alter query values, without needing to parse a string. What you want is something like this:

```
l(t($row['salon_name']),'admin/content/edit-salons-products-services', array('query' => array('side' => $row['salon_id'])));
```

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, just thought I'd link my roughly equivalent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278135/i-want-to-use-the-question-mark-in-the-auto-generated-path-aliases/6289405#6289405

Comment: This is definitely the best approach.